# Correcting biased polling

Tags: estimation, forecasting, meta-analysis, bias, polling

Let's say I'm polling for a binary election in different states with known biases. Furthermore, let's say I only manage to poll only a small sample of people in each of these states. How would you combine the results to come up with the best estimate for the election?

My best guess is the normalized vote is: 
$$
\sum_i \frac{\text{# polled in state}_i}{\text{# total polled}} * \text{normalized vote}
$$
where 
$$
\text{normalized vote} = \frac{p(d) - \text{average}(p(d))}{\text{stdev}( p(d))}
$$
Assuming $d$ is one of the binary choices, and I have a history of $p(d)$ in each state.

Comment: You need to clarify how the election works.  I think it is clear you say there just one winner for the whole country.  But are they decided by a majority of total votes; or a majority of states (each of which is decided by a majority of votes)?, with states operating like a UK electorate?  Or does each state get a certain number of votes, like in a USA electoral college?  Finally by "known biases" can you clarify that you mean "history of voting disproportionately for one of the parties."

Comment: What do you mean by "known biases" exactly?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The election is a simple majority of the votes. The "known biases" are the results from previous polls. Assume I've run many previous polls, and each state tends to vote d with probability avg(p(d)).

Comment: Peter Ellis is right. With what you proposed, you can estimate *something like* the average vote across the states, but (a) this won't even be the proportion of the popular vote, and (b) the actual legislated mechanics of voting would probably introduce some corrections.

Answer (score 1):

How about a mixed effects model of some sort where

$p(d_{s,i,t})=f(\beta_s+\alpha_{s,t}+\gamma_t+\epsilon_i)$

Where $\beta_s$ is a fixed state effect estimated from the previous elections or polls, $\alpha_{s,t}$ is a random state effect for this particular poll at this particular time, $\gamma_t$ is the overall mood of the nation at the time of this poll.  You would estimate the $\beta_s$ from the previous poll or election data.  $\epsilon_i$ is a random variable reflecting individual randomness.

You would need some serious constraints on the $\alpha_{s,i}$ to make this estimatable, in fact you might want to set them all to zero, but I've left them in for completeness in case there's a clever way to use them.  More generally, there's a range of possible ways of finishing this off, constraining the model and estimating parameters.

Once you've fit the model you can use it with the full population data to estimate the total result.

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful. How would you take into account the number of polled people?

Comment: The actual poll would be the sample you fit the model to.  The numbers per state in the whole country would be the population set that you use for prediction